# The distribution of a complicated function

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics

It is quite some time that I am looking for a way to solve this problem theoretically.

Let $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$, $\mu \geq 0$ then what is the distribution of
$$
Y=\sqrt{|X|} \times \Phi(X;\mu,\sigma)
$$

it may look funny but I can estimate the mean and sd of $Y$ by a simple formula:

$$
\mu_Y=.5\times\sqrt{\frac{2\times \mu+\sigma}{2}} \\
$$
$$
\sigma_Y=.5\times\sqrt{\frac{\mu+\sigma}{2}} \\
$$

Here is a code to show the estimate:

```
mu = 2
sigma = 4
x = rnorm(10000, mu, sigma)
y = sqrt(abs(x)) * pnorm(x, mu, sigma)
hist(y)
abline(v = mean(y))

# Mu_Y
print(mean(y))
print(sqrt(2 * mu + sigma) / 2 ^ (3 / 2))


# Sigma_Y
sd(y)
print(sqrt(mu + sigma) / (2 ^ (3 / 2)))
```

[image]

Comment: There is no closed form, because evaluating the distribution function $F_Y(y)$ requires you to find the probability of the event $X^2\Phi(X;\mu,\sigma)^2 \le y^2$ ($\Phi$ is the Normal CDF). Consider, *inter alia,* numerical methods to find the boundary of this event.

Comment: Hello @whuber :). it should be |X|*CDF^2

Comment: Right -- I forgot about the square root.  Unfortunately that change doesn't help you any.

Comment: When you say "complex" do you mean "complicated"?

Comment: @Henry yes sorry

Comment: The notation $P(X<x)$ is incorrect: judging from the code it should be $\Phi(X;\mu,\sigma)$